# Is the image stabilization of Fuji X-S1 enough to make photos with largest zoom from hand?

Tags: image-stabilization, fujifilm, superzoom

I've found [Fuji X-S1](http://www.neocamera.com/camera/fuji/xs1) quite interesting but I haven't found answer to the question that is important to me:

According to the specification the camera has build-in image stabilization. It has also large zoon (26x). But is that build-in image stabilization enough to enable to do photos with big zoom (10x-26x) holding the camera in hand? Of course, I'm talking about optimistic scenario - outdoor and sunny day.

Comment: According to @DJClayworth it should be on-topic here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64164/cameras-and-photo-gear-reviews/64176#64176

Comment: The question could be made more on-topic by editing to remove the camera model. That is, the question is "does IS help with big zoom cameras"?

Comment: @DanWolfgang why? It's good answerable and it's about the technical parameters of specific camera. Making it general wouldn't give me answer to my question and would be probably too broad...

Comment: I think the question is on topic here and fine with the specific model. The difference between this and some of your other questions is that those were asking for _really_ subjective comparisons (and for example wondering if they would meet _your_ expectations).

Comment: @mattdm but I was really trying hard to objectivise my concerns... I'm not sure how could I ask about comparing the parameters of various cameras here...

Comment: @ŁukaszL. as you can see from AJ's answer, the question is dependent upon the max shutter speed and not the camera.

Comment: @DanWolfgang - yes, but the actual focal length of the lens and the maximum shutter speed on the particular model do make a difference for the overall question.  If the camera only went to 1/1000 shutter speed, it would be a lot more touchy.  Since he gave x multipliers for the zoom amount, I think it's safe to say that he didn't know which specs were relevant to list, so giving the model is the next best thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With sufficient light, you can shoot anything free hand, even without image stabilization.  Your hand can only move so fast and shutter speeds can often get very quick.

The XS-1 has a 1/4000 shutter and the lens goes to the equivalent of 623mm for a 35mm camera.

The general rule of thumb is that the shutter speed for free hand should be somewhere between 1/focal length to 1/5*focal length.  Even taking the most conservative version of this, 623*5 is only 3115.

This means that 1/4000 shutter speed is fast enough to take a free hand photo at the max zoom of the X-S1 even with the image stabilization turned off.  So if you have enough light for 1/4000 shutter speed or probably even 1/3000, you are fine without IS on.  Depending on the strength of the IS you might be able to even get down to around 1/600th second exposures without a tripod.

Comment: So, the question only is, give shutten 1/4000 enough light, even in very sunny day? The maximal light by maximal zoom is F/5.6

Comment: @ŁukaszL. Take a look at the [handy chart in this answer](http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/20170/1943). (Spoiler: at ISO 400, f/5.6 and ¹⁄₄₀₀₀ will give nominally correct exposure under typical full sun.)