# Illumination question

Tags: exposure

I meter a surface at ASA 100 and get F4 at 1/15 second.
What is the illumination coming off that surface in Cd/square foot ?

Comment: Probably best asking this on physics.stackexchange

Comment: Maybe [How to calculate Lux from EV?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/10093/how-to-calculate-lux-from-ev)

Comment: I think the linked question contains the information you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This [Kodak reference](http://www.kodak.com/cluster/global/en/consumer/products/techInfo/am105/am105kic.shtml) for estimating luminance and illuminance may help.

Your metering at ISO 100, 1/15th and f/4 would be equivalent to ISO 400, 1/30th and f/5.6 if I've done the math correctly. So use their value for f/5.6 which is 2.67 Cd/ft2